# Classical/Arabic author giveninits exception

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I'm using `biblatex-chicago` and I have to use `giveninits` for my thesis style. When it comes to classical Arabic author names, which are composite with lots of "Abu" and "Ibn" (e.g. "Abu Hamid") I would like to override the ugly first name abbreviation,

[image: unwanted abbreviated author]

to get this beauty instead,

[image: desired output]

So I have been trying to fiddle with the `\relax` hack as suggested elsewhere, but then I start getting an unwanted dot.
[image: unwanted dot]

If I then use `\nopunct`, the point goes missing when needed in the bibliography.

I don't mind modifying the database entries. Here is a MWE with another title for comparison. Ideally, the English author should be abbreviated, but not the Arabic. I guess this question also applies to some classical and medieval authors; you wouldn't want to have "L. Vinci" instead of "Leonardo da Vinci", I reckon. Is there a simple way to bypass or override the `giveninits` option?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ghazali1999,
  title =       "Ihya Ulum al-Din",
  author =      "{\relax \Abu Hamid} al-Ghazali",
%  shortauthor =    "al-Ghazali",
  date =            "1999",
  publisher =       "ITS"
}
@book{john1989,
  title =       "English Book",
  author =      "Johnny English",
  date =            "1989",
  publisher =       "Easy"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{ghazali1999} and some other text\footcite{john1989}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could locally set `giveninits=false` for Arabic names. We only need to define `giveninits` as an entry option for this to work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ghazali1999,
  title =       "Ihya Ulum al-Din",
  author =      "Abu Hamid al-Ghazali",
  options = {giveninits=false},
%  shortauthor =    "al-Ghazali",
  date =            "1999",
  publisher =       "ITS"
}
@book{john1989,
  title =       "English Book",
  author =      "Johnny English",
  date =            "1989",
  publisher =       "Easy"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{giveninits}[true]{%
  \settoggle{abx@bool@giveninits}{#1}}

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{ghazali1999} and some other text\footcite{john1989}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

It might be nice if this option was available by default, but there are a few details to sort out first. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/760

With the answer as posted here the `uniquename` still only considers the initials even of entries with `giveninits=false` and so may give unexpected results.